# Eclipse CDT not identifying functions for Eigen types

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to import a C++11 project into eclipse. The code builds from an existing Makefile and it works all right. I have been able to make Eclipse use the existing makefile and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) also helped with getting C++11 support going in eclipse. I am using the eigen library and the include paths for it are set, and eclipse is able to recognize the types of eigen objects.

Eclipse is not able to recognize the all the types and functions from header files included recursively.

The former represents itself as

```
a.b.c()
```

and Eclipse will claim that method c could not be resolved. Here a is a struct and b is an eigen type. The types of a and b are recognized correctly. Here b is a Vector2i and c() is the function y() that is available on Vector2i

The latter problem is that I have a bunch of header files that I need to include in a lot of places, so I made a common header file that includes them and now I just include the common header file everywhere. Now eclipse is complaining that functions declarations in individual header files are not not resolved. If I include the header files individually, then eclipse is OK, but I really don't want to do that.

I am using CDT for the first time so any ideas on how (or which) eclipse settings to check/fix  would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps what is happening is eclipse is parsing the source files, and although the common include file is just a header, meaning that when eclipse runs make, g++ still navigates the directory correctly, but the common header file itself is not on the build path or something, and is not being indexed. An alternative idea, is that it is being indexed, but that it is only applied to a single file because of the ifndef/define wrappers. If the latter is the case, then perhaps the indexer is applying the information to a single file. Report back with that information-is a single file working fine?

Comment: The common header file is in the same directory as the rest of the header files. So it is being parsed.  I could just grit my teeth and include all the individual header files manually if I had no other option, but the eigen situation is more problematic as it is used everywhere. And the spurious errors are spoiling the point of using an IDE.

Comment: There are a few macros defined in the common header file, they are recognized ok.

Comment: Don't reconcile the problem by bending over to the problem: this can be solved. I'm sure that others have had the same problem too. Eclipse has some indexer settings that you might want to play with. One of them has to do with making the indexer work from a specific configuration at all times or the active build configuration. Project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Indexer. Try changing that appropriately, perhaps even restart eclipse after doing so.