# Dereference operator for unique_ptr does not work in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, unique-ptr

After following the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) I managed to make Eclipse (Indigo) recognize `unique_ptr` (and other C++11 new stuff). The problem is that `operator->` for `unique_ptr` seems not to be supported in Eclipse. Here you have an example:

```
class Foo { void bar() { /* ... */ } };

std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
(*foo).bar(); // 1
foo->bar();   // 2
```

Case `1` works as expected: there is no error and autocompletion works. For case `2`, however, Eclipse marks the statement with an error ("Method 'bar' could not be resolved"), plus autocompletion from `foo->` does not work.

Most interestingly, I do not have any problems with `std::shared_ptr`. It only happens for `std::unique_ptr`.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Does anyone know a way to fix it?

**EDIT:** just for clarifying purposes, the compilation process goes fine for the code snippet shown above. So, the problem is not in the compiler itself, but on Eclipse.

Comment: @dirk: the question is about autocompletion and static lint-picking in the IDE; no mention of compilation issues.

Comment: @dirkgently I am using g++ 4.6, so compilation goes fine. The problem only affects to Eclipse.

Comment: @Rock: Right. I missed that bit.

Comment: Even the compilers do not yet fully support C++11, so I would expect eclipse (which is notoriously behind) to support all of it it only far after the compilers do.

Comment: I used to develop C++ application with CDT, but I found its approach (understanding C++ semantics on its own, thus giving you errors without relying on an external compiler) abysmal. Fun impossible exercise: try to make eclipse not complaining about CLOCKS_PER_SEC (which is obviously a macro which isn't defined in any header since it's "virtual") being undefined. They should do something like what XCode does: integrate CDT with LLVM's wonderful infrastructure and use it. In the meanwhile, I switched back to GVim, I'm an happier developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374993) in CDT describing the very same problem that I am suffering. So far, there is not a real fix for the problem but there is a workaround explained in that bug report:

> Yes, GCC 4.5 is the latest GCC version whose library headers can be accurately
>   indexed by CDT. The main reason for failing to index 4.6 headers is CDT's lack
>   of support for 'constexpr' and 'nullptr', which are used extensively in the 4.6
>   headers (any chance of that being implemented for Juno, by the way?).
>
> I have worked around this by having both GCC 4.5 and 4.6 installed on my
>   system, and pointing CDT to 4.5's headers (by setting the compiler invocation
>   command to 'g++-4.5' in Discovery Options) while actually compiling with 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been recently fixed, in cdt 8.1.1. Just go **help->check for updates** and it will be downloaded and installed. I've tested unique_ptr and it is properly indexed.