# Eclipse does not recognize types from stdint.h for ARM Windows GCC toolchain

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse Juno for C/C++ developers installed together with GNU ARM C/C++ Development Support plug-in from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse.

In my project I am using types like `uint_32t`, `int16_t` and `uint8_t` than normally comes from `stdint.h`. While I forced the Eclipse to see the standard headers of my compiler by directly pointing the directory where the `include` directory lies, mentioned types are not resolved. This gives me a lot of red markings about unresolved symbols and do some problems with code completion of the functions declared with these types.

The same problem is with standard macro definitions like **GNUC** - normally CDT see these for GNU C or GNU C++, but with toolchain set to ARM Windows GCC it don't. Strange.

What can I do to resolve that and return the main boost Eclipse gives in productivity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I found solution to my problem. The problem was the **CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings** provider, which tried to run the `gcc` instead of `arm-elf-gcc`. I added prefix to the field `Command to get compiler specs:`¹ to invoke compiler by its proper name.

And voilà, all unresolved symbols disappeared.

*Unfortunately I broke my project by changing toolchains (never do this if you have GNU ARM Eclipse plugin installed!) but that is another story.*

---

<sup>¹ - It is under: `Project Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.`, the tab `Providers`; `Share settings entries between projects (global provider)` has to be disabled to edit that field.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

please note that [GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/) plugins were updated in Oct 2013, and the new version has better support for path discovery, so this problem is less likely to occur.

changing toolchains was also fixed.

Comment: This should better be posted as comment, not a an answer.

Comment: ok. my first attempt was to post a comment, but it was rejected (not enough rights, or something like this).

Comment: Hi Mr. @LiviuIonescu ,Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033130/how-to-use-the-gdb-gnu-debugger-for-microcontroller-debugging
I know that you're probably one of the only people out there with deep knowledge about this topic. Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using external Makefile, Eclipse has no way of knowing where your standard library for the target platform is located. The solution, that I have found, is to add the library include paths to

`Project->Preferences->C++ General->Paths and symbols`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution from [this page](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/7/development-with-gcc-and-eclipse/) helped solving it:

- Enter project properties -> C/C++->Preprocessor Include Paths,etc.->Providers
- Click on CDT GCC Build Output Parser and change the compiler command pattern from `(gcc)|([gc]++)|(clang)` to `(arm-none-eabi-gcc)|([gc]++)|(clang)`
- Click apply button
- Click on CDT Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM and replace `${COMMAND}` with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.
- Click apply button.

Comment: This is because `${FLAGS}` needs to be set to the compiler flags from your Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

In `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Paths > Providers`:

- Enable `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM`.
- Set `Command to get compiler specs` to:

  ```
  arm-none-eabi-g++ ${FLAGS} ${cross_toolchain_flags} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}".C
  ```

  - The important part is the `.C` on the end. This is usually set depending on the language. A small `.c` is used for C code, while the big C is used for C++. But there are no languages specified when using an external makefile or with the `no toolchain` option set.
- Also, check `Allocate console in the Console View` to check the command is running properly and the variables are being correctly substituted.
- Enable `CDT GCC Build Output Parser` and change the compiler command pattern from `(gcc)|([gc]\+\+)|(clang)` to `(.*g++)|(.*gcc)|(.*[gc]\+\+)` then apply changes. Use the `Move up/down` buttons to move it above the `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM`.

---

You will also need to set `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Paths > Entries > CDT User Settings Entries` to the following:

[image: cdt user settings entries]

In `Preferences > String Substitutions` you will need to create a var for `gnu-arm-path` pointing to your toolchain home.

Ideally, these should be found in `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM`, but in my case they are not. I think it is to do with the fact that in a managed project, these entries are tied to each language. But with an external makefile the languages list box just says `[Unspecified]`.

---

The Eclipse scanner provider system seems to be designed around CDT managed projects, making it a little trickier to get working when you are using an external makefile.

You can create a new managed project with an external makefile and view the scanner discovery console to see how it should be working. This is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a totally different solution to my version of this (in)famous problem. In my case search paths where not the problem because the compiler was working fine. Nevertheless, the editor complained about unresolved cstdint types everywhere: very annoying. Googling for the solution using the error message string was not fruitful and very frustrating.

I found the solution of this problem by chance in an answer ("There's now a new way to solve this without the GXX_EXPERIMENTAL hack") to the following thread:

[Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support/13549029#13549029)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that `PATH` did not direct to the compiler. So I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2017-q4-major\bin` to the variable and it worked.
To clarify: we had a convention, that we direct to the compiler with the variable `GCCPATH`.

Answer (score -1):

See if Project -> C/C++ Index -> Freshen All Files helps.