# eclipse show error on mutex type , despite the fact that compilation passed ok

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, eclipse-cdt

Use eclipse-cdt (latest version ) on Ubuntu.
I create new project with one line code - mutex declarative.

compilation passed (compile with eclipse), but eclipse mark the mutex in red and complain on - 'mutex type could not be resolved'

i add ' -std=c++0x -pthread' to the g++ and refresh eclipse indexer, but didnt help.

Any advice?

```
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

static mutex m;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Comment: Does changing `-std=c++0x` to `-std=c++11` make any difference? Are you using the latest versions of Eclipse and GCC?

Comment: change to -std=c++11 dosnt work. compilation dosnt passed as well with this option. i am using latest version of eclipse. i asume the gcc ok , because build passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols -> GNU C++. Click "Add..." and paste `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (ensure to append and prepend two underscores) into "Name" and leave "Value" blank.

This solve it.

Comment: The other option is to add the '--std=c++0x' (or c++11) to the eclipse discovery options, and then clear the discovery information.  What eclipse does is run g++ with the options provided and captures a list of all of the symbols that are defined.

Comment: I didn't understand the explanation on the discovery options? what is it the discovery option? why do i manage the g++ options in 2 palaces (i added it in the MISC )? why do i need to clear the discovery?  Thank you!!!! it sound very interesting.

Comment: Under your project properties, type discovery into the search box. One of the things it should bring up 'C++ Build/Discovery Options'  It lists both the command line options for discovery (where you should list '-std=c++0x') and a clear button which causes it to relearn the built in symbols defined by the compiler on your next build.

Comment: I know where is it. My questions is what is it? why do i manage the g++ options in 2 places (i added it in the MISC )? why do i need to clear the discovery?

Comment: You don't HAVE to, it's another option to setting __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ manually. Basically, the first time you compile your project, Eclipse CDT (the C++ Developer Tools) runs the compiler with the options at the bottom of that page.  It causes the compiler to output every compiler defined #define, so that the indexer knows which symbols have already been set.  If you only add '-std=c++0x' to the misc options, then it doesn't use it for discovery and it isn't aware of `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`.  You have to set it the misc options regardless.

Answer (score 1):

-D__cplusplus=201103L helped me. Using Eclipse Luna. **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** didn't help

Comment: __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ didn't work for me either, though I should point out that you added an extra c. It should be -D__cplusplus=201103L

Comment: Like spectacularbob said, the symbok name is __cplusplus and the value 201103L