# Ubuntu 12.04 C++11 code not working

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, eclipse-cdt

This had been bending my mind in the last few days. I also wasn't sure whether to post this in ask ubuntu or here. I chose here to get a wider programmer-based audience.

I am brand new to Ubuntu and GCC, however I've been programming C++ on windows for about 5 years. This simple C++11 code sample works fine on my Windows machine with VS2010.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> func;

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

With Eclipse CDT (Ubuntu 12.04), I get the error `Symbol 'function' could not be resolved`.

I've made sure `build-essentials` is installed.

I've added `/usr/include/c++/4.6.3` to my includes in eclipse.

I've added `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to Paths and Symbols in eclipse.

I've tried -std=c++11 on the command line.

I've tried -std=c++0x on the command line.

I've followed the Accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113291/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-7 and installed gcc 4.7

Is this not supported with gcc?

I've checked `auto` and it works, but things like `unique_ptr` don't work either, same error as above.

Sorry again, I'm new to Linux.

**Edit:**
As per n.m.'s request:

```
neil@ubuntu12:~/projects/Test/Test$ g++ -v;g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
neil@ubuntu12:~/projects/test$
```

Comment: Did you use the --std=c++11 command line option?

Comment: Yes I've tried that and --std=c++0x, sorry I'll include that in the question.

Comment: Don't define `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` manually. You're not supposed to.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes - I followed instructions somewhere that said to add it to eclipse's Paths and Symbols list. It didn't work anyway :(

Comment: Anyway, "Symbol 'function' could not be resolved" does not look like a GCC error. Can you post the errors you get when you try it on the command-line?

Comment: From the command line please do: `g++ -v; g++ -std=c++0x -o test test.C`, and include the output of these commands in your question.

Comment: well, you need to substitute your own source file name in place of `test` ;)

Comment: I think its working. No errors on command line.

Comment: `neil@ubuntu12:~/projects/Test/Test$ ./main`
`Hello, world!` This is embarrassing... I've created a question for no reason...

Comment: _"Is this not supported with gcc?"_ GCC supports it fine, you're confusing an error from Eclipse saying its syntax highlighting and auto-completion couldn't recognise `std::function` with a compiler error from GCC. They're not the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this not supported with gcc?

GCC supports it fine, you're confusing an error from Eclipse saying its syntax highlighting and auto-completion couldn't recognise `std::function` with a compiler error from GCC. They're not the same thing.

> I've added `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to Paths and Symbols in eclipse.

This says how to make Eclipse CDT recognise C++11 names: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features

Comment: Yes, I figured that much. I posted my own answer but it was deleted. The link is very helpful though, thanks :)