# How to compile C++11 in Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, c++11, eclipse-cdt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

I tried everything to compile C++11 code namely `std::unique_ptr` and it never compiles.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) and [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features) yet it still doesn't compile. I also installed gcc 4.7, and made sure that it's added to the includes directories of my eclipse c++ project, yet it still doesn't work!!

Is there anything missing please?

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to the command line.

Comment: what compilation errors do you get?

Comment: @KerrekSB error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’

Comment: @juanchopanza 

`main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
`main.cpp:69:14: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’`
`main.cpp:69:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’`
`main.cpp:69:30: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’`
`main.cpp:69:30: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘char’
`main.cpp:69:7: warning: unused variable ‘text’ [-Wunused-variable]`

When compiling this:

`auto text = std::unique_ptr<char>(new char[10]);`

Comment: @AhmedFakhry sounds like Eclipse is not using the GCC 4.7 you installed.

Comment: Try running "g++ --version" on a command line, to see whether 4.7 is actually the "default" compiler. If not, you have to somehow tell Eclipse to use it, or somehow tell the Ubuntu system to make "g++" the 4.7 version.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I made sure that its directories are added to the include directories of the project

Comment: @ChristianStieber you are right, it's using gcc 4.6.3, how can I make it use 4.7 by default?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes that's what I'm using

Comment: @AhmedFakhry: Did you `#include <memory>` and qualify the name as `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @AhmedFakhry the include directories only point it to the right header files. There should be some other option to point it to the right binaries (I don't know where that option would be, I'm not very familiar with Eclipse).

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you so much. This is the answer, please add it below so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which language standard GCC defaults to depends on how it has been compiled, but most distributions still set this to something like `gnu++98` for C++. To use C++11, you have to pass one of the following language standard options:

```bsh
g++ --std=c++0x     # <= 4.6.*

g++ --std=c++11     # >= 4.7.* (but c++0x is still accepted)
```

To use a unique pointer:

```c
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<base[]> AllYourBase(::new base[1024]);
```