# eclipse cdt doesn't like class member initializers

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse CDT 8.1.1

The issue is that, when using C++11 class member initializers, it complains that the members are not initialized.
It's still expecting an initializer list.

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {} // warning: Member `m_bar` was not initialized in this constructor
 private:
  int m_bar = 0;
};
```

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: And it accepts the syntax, but just gives the warning?

Comment: yes. It's not a huge issue, it just makes all of those warnings (even the real ones) useless because I can't tell the difference.

Comment: Oh, right. If I understand, it's the IDE not being updates for C++11, but the compiler is. If that's the case, it's like the new CTP release for VS and the best you can hope for is to compile it and get actual warnings from the compiler.

Comment: That's too bad. I was kind of expecting that answer though :/

Comment: How about ignore this warning? Something like #pragma warning(...)

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)?

Comment: See this section from the [Eclipse CDT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features).

Comment: Eclipse Juno doesn't support this syntax yet. The bug tracker has a bug for all C++11 features in gcc4.7 (which covers N2756, this feature) is here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363234