# Does libstdc++ not implement std::stoi?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std

I want to use `std::stoi`. Although I could use `::atoi(str.c_str())` it would make the code cleaner if this would work. But Eclipse tells me:

> Function 'stoi' could not be resolved

I checked that

- the header `<string>` is included,
- include paths are set correctly, as I can use `std::string`,
- the compiler flag `-std=c++0x -std=c++11` is set too.

Is `stoi()` missing in gcc, or is it somehow my fault?

I am using gcc (Debian 4.7.2-4) 4.7.2.

Comment: If anything, it would be missing from libstdc++, not GCC...

Comment: Is the compiler flag not `-std=c++0x` ?

Comment: Yes, just checked it. Both are set.

Comment: You should probably have only `-std=c++11`.  Can't imagine that would cause this bug though.  (Also, just to confirm, you are either using `std::stoi` or pulling in the std namespace?)    Wait.... Will it compile?  Like Nikos C. said below, it might just be Eclipse complaining.

Comment: @DevNoob: it is not about gcc. Please, rename the question.

Comment: Omg its annoying how blind people vote for close.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using GCC 4.7.2, so `std::stoi` is supported. You can ignore the Eclipse warning. It should compile and run fine. The problem is with the Eclipse editor, not with GCC.

(You only need the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` [to also get the GCC extensions] flag, btw. `-std=c++0x` is just a deprecated synonym.)

Comment: ``c++11`` and ``gnu++11`` are different.

Comment: @SergeyK. I know. But both enable C++-11 support.

Comment: Okay, yes your right. It compiles. Can I somehow do something aganist these Eclipse errors?

Comment: @DevNoob Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support

Comment: +1 Hah, nice one. Try to compile it before taking *Eclipse*'s stupid complaints too serious.

Answer (score 5):

You can get rid of the red squiggles in eclipse, (from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/373462/909018/#msg_909018)):

Project Properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros->[Providers] tab->your Built-in Compiler Settings provider (toolchain dependent).
Click on "Workspace Settings" link which gets you to "Settings" property page, select [Discovery] tab and your provider again. There is "Command to get compiler specs", add "-std=c++11" in there.

hit apply and close everything, then index->rebuild and you should be all set.

Or, if your version of eclipse is older, you might just have to do this:

Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Discovery Options->GCC C++ Compiler

and add the "-std=c++11" flag to the invocation arguments there. This is "deprecated" though, so you may want to consider updating Eclipse since you're updating your compiler too.

Comment: I read this in the eclipse FAQ, but the problem was, that it was not set permanent. It chnaged nothing and after reopening project settings the flag has dissapeared.

Comment: It fixed it permanently for me. You might have to close eclipse and re-open?

Comment: Goddamn. okay its permanent. But `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` solves the  `stoi` problem. But raises a `vector.insert` problem. but your way does not solve `stoi` problem. Its horrible.