# 'stoi' was not declared in this scope after using -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Most probably this is weird, but when I got this error that **stoi wasn't declared in this scope**, I smiled because I am familiar with this error and it's solution.

I checked this option ***have g++ follow the c++11 ISO c++ language standard [-std=c++11]*** in compiler settings of Code Blocks (16.01, with MinGW) and tried recompiling it, but surprisingly it didn't work and the same error persisted. I tried re-installing CodeBlocks  but that didn't work.

Also, I tried with windows power shell and command prompt with `g++ math_handler.cpp -std=c++11` but got the same error.[image]

What am I doing wrong?

the code is here:

```
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string body="456";
    int i=stoi(body);
}
```

**Note**:

1. I tried with `-std=c++0x` and g++ too.
2. the same problem with `to_string()` function.
3. gcc version 4.9.2 (tdm -1)

Comment: Run `g++ -v` from the command line. Keep an eye out for the version number. If it's below 4.8 c++11 support is iffy. Also make sure you've included `<string>`. Beyond that, not much we can do without seeing your code.

Comment: What headers did you include?

Comment: Wait a sec! gcc! You may have just run the C compiler.

Comment: and give `std::stoi` a try.

Comment: @user4581301 gcc version 4.9.2

Comment: More than enough. try `g++ math_handler.cpp -std=c++11` to make sure you are compiling for C++ and if that fails add a [mcve].

Comment: @NikosC. yeah, sure. have a look at my code, I added the code.

Comment: Nearly identical to the test case I threw together. The only way I can get it to fail is if I compiler it as C with gcc instead of g++.

Comment: Well, you seem to have found a mingw bug then. Use `std::stoi`, outlined in the answer below. Does that work?

Comment: @NikosC. No, I tried that too, but compiler says 'stoi isn't part of std'

Comment: @user4581301 so, it's a bug?

Comment: There we go. I am being stupid. Left out the `-std=c++11` No longer confirmed.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/q5ndAW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found that it is a known bug in MinGW bundled with CodeBlocks. I found the solution [here](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string).

> 1. Download [mingw-to-string-gcc47.zip](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string-gcc47.zip) which contains three patched
>      header files. (Original patches: [wchar.h](http://tehsausage.com/paste/wchar-diff), [stdio.h](http://tehsausage.com/paste/stdio-diff-3bc0), [os_defines.h](http://tehsausage.com/paste/os-defines-diff))
> 2. Copy *wchar.h* and *stdio.h* from the include directory in the zip file
>      to the following directory (overwrite):  *C:\mingw\include* (replace
>      C:\mingw\ with the appropriate directory)
> 3. Copy *os_defines.h* to the following directory (overwrite): 
>      *C:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits* (replace
>      C:\mingw\ with the appropriate directory) (replace 4.7.0 with the
>      correct version number)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the required header file? 
    `#include <string>`

stoi is also in the std namespace so:

```
std::stoi()
```

or:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman And what is the error message you get when using `std::stoi`?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034197/compile-error-stoi-is-not-a-member-of-std

Comment: No, don't recommend `using namespace std;`, Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.