# Parsing int in C++11 - stoi

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, namespaces, std

I am trying to take a string and parse it into an int.  I have read the many answers out there, and it seems that using `stoi` is the most up-to-date way.  It appears to me that `stoi` uses `std`, but I am getting `Function 'stoi' could not be resolved` despitre `using namespace std;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string line = "";
    string five = "5";
    int number = stoi(five); //Error here with stoi
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Update:

I am using Eclipse.  My flags are:  `-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11`

Comment: You forgot to tell us which is your compiler, and how you are compiling this program.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453765?

Comment: plab nice find plab. good eye! post that in your answer for a big green check mark

Comment: You still haven't told us what compiler, what version, or anything like that. Please get into the habit of being _precise_.

Comment: Personally I like stringstream for this case. `istringstream iss(five); iss >> number;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle on C++11 support in your compiler flags. `-std=c++11` for a recent gcc. For Eclipse, please refer to the [corresponding question](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features) in the FAQ and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454125/3146587) explains how to get rid of the remaining Eclipse warning.

Comment: Cool thanks.  Know the name of the file by any chance?  I am running it in Eclipse at the moment.

Comment: @Evorlor: The name of what file?

Comment: I am not actually compiling this in the terminal.  I am coding this in Eclipse.

Comment: @plabatut Hmmm...thank you, but that did not appear to solve the problem

Comment: @Evorlor Note that eclipse is an IDE; It doesn't actually compile your programs (at least not to get an executable, for the pedantic). For that, it will invoke an external compiler just like you would on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GCC or MINGW, then this is the answer:
[std::stoi doesn't exist in g++ 4.6.1 on MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543540/2056153)

> This is a result of a non-standard declaration of vswprintf on
>   Windows. The GNU Standard Library defines
>   _GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF on this platform, which in turn disables the conversion functions you're attempting to use. You can
>   read more about this issue and macro here:
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37522.
>
> If you're willing to modify the header files distributed with MinGW,
>   you may be able to work around this by removing the
>   !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF) macro on line 2754 of
>   .../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h, and adding
>   it back around lines 2905 to 2965 (the lines that reference
>   std::vswprintf). You won't be able to use the std::to_wstring
>   functions, but many of the other conversion functions should be
>   available.

Please always provide platform and compiler information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are amenable to parsing an int another way, how about using an STL algorithm and a C++11 lambda expression?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "12345";

    int num = 0;

    for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [&num](char c){ num = 10 * num + (c - '0');  });

    cout << str << " = " << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I think the

    { int number; istringstream iss("5"); iss >> number; }

approach suggested by Brandin is more general and suitable.