# Eclipse CDT parser support for C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 with CDT 8.0.2 on Linux.  How can I configure the CDT to recognize c++11 syntax, specifically **`override`**?  Currently the parser flags a bogus error on the line indicated.  The build completes without error since I include -std=c++11 in my compiler command lines.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(){}
    virtual ~foo(){}
    virtual void func(){}
};

class bar : public foo
{
public:
    bar(){}
    virtual ~bar(){}
    virtual void func() override {} // <--- parser incorrectly flags syntax error
};

int main()
{
    bar my_bar;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the directions on the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) without success.  Again, I only need the editor's parser to recognize c++11, the actual build is fine.

Answer (score 5):

To fix C++11 syntax highlighting go to:

**Project Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols --> Symbols --> GNU C++**

and overwrite the symbol (i.e. add new symbol):

```
__cplusplus
```

with value

```
201103L
```

Make sure that indexer is enabled in project settings (**C/C++ general --> Indexer**)

Then reindex (**Project --> C/C++ Index --> Rebuild**)

if the problem still persist reindex once again.
It should work now.

Comment: good solution, I put this at the top of my header file in the source code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define a `override` macro with no content for the parser only in your Project "Properties/Preprocessor Includes/CDT User Settings".

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved itself for me when I installed the development version of eclipse:

Eclipse Luna 4.4 CDT 8.4