# C++11 override keyword not recognized in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, overriding, syntax-error

I am working with Eclipse (Indigo) IDE for C++ Developers. I am using make file to build the project. I am using keyword `override` for virtual functions in derived class so that the compiler warns me if the function does not match the declaration in base class. However, Eclipse highlights the line with yellow indicating syntax error. I have followed the steps as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support). Any more suggestions of how I get could eclipse to recognize the keyword `override`

Comment: It almost certainly means that the C++11 support of the compiler-version that Eclipse is executing does not yet include the "override" keyword. What compiler and version is it?

Comment: I am using make file and g++ with appropriate flags for compiling. But this error is not at the compile stage. It is the error in Eclipse editor. I thought there could be a way of Eclipse recognizing `override` keyword.