# Can't find the tool settings in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am looking to add a few libraries to Eclipse CDT (latest version 8.2). However under the project -> properties -> c/c++ build -> settings....There is no tool settings tab where I can configure my include files and the linker like I see with so many other tutorials online. What appears is what is shown below. Is this new for the newest version of the eclipse CDT or did something get configured improperly in the download. Thanks for the help.

[image: Pic of Eclipse]

Answer (score 17):

Go to Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Builder Settings -> (x) Generate Makefiles automatically 
then the tool settings tab under Settings will appear

Comment: this is **not** working under Eclipse 3.8.1 for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: My "Generate Makefiles automatically" box was already checked, but I unchecked it and re-checked it and lo and behold! Tool Settings appeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Same Problem here, with KEPLER.
I switched `C/C++ Build->Builder Settings->Builder type` to `External Builder` and closed the properties window. When reopening properties the `C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings Tab` was available.

Edit: If the `External Builder` switch is disabled, it can help to change the toolchain settings. By switching to e.g. **MinGW** and **back**, the switch becomes accessible.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Includes, symbols, libraries, and other references should be under "C/C++ General" | "Paths and Symbols" (I'm using Juno)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to apply another tool-chain. Under Project->Properties->C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor. I unchecked "Display compatible toolchains only" and selected Cross GCC.

After apply and OK, I could edit the Tool Settings and add include-paths there.

Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a proper tool chain installed in Eclipse.
Open Eclipse/Help/Install New Software ...
Click on the **"already installed"** link in the bottom right corner.

[image]

If your tool chain is not there:

- Select **All available sites** from the **Work with** combobox.
- Expand **Programming Languages**
- Select your tools and install