# Can't get Eclipse CDT to work with C++11

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I've tried everything I can find, including the official [Eclipse CDT Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features) and a couple posts here, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) one, and [another article I found](http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36441490955/eclipse-mingw-builds); none of which proved to be successful.

When I try and build my project I get a "has not been declared" error on all C++11 commands, and the editor still underlines these commands.

My current settings:

- Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Cygwin C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Added `-std=c++0x` to the end (and I've tried `-std=c++11`)
- Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Cygwin C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Added `-std=c++0x` to the end (and I've tried `-std=c++11`)
- Properties > C/C++ Build > Discovery Options > Cygwin C++ Compiler > Added `-std=c++0x` to the end of Compiler invocation arguments (and I've tried `-std=c++11`)
- Cleared discovered entries

I've also tried adding `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to my Symbols.

I'm using the Cygwin + GCC 4.8.2 compiler and Eclipse Indigo (with the latest CDT updates) if that helps.

Thanks!

Oh, and on a side note, does anyone know if Eclipse CDT is going to eventually support C++11 without having to go through all this trouble?

Comment: Go to your project properties -> C/C++ Build / Settings, select the active configuration and the Tool Settings tab, then the line for your compiler (maybe "MinGW C++ Compiler" or similar). What does it say in "All options"? I suspect your `-fmessage-length=` options is messed up. Mine says `-fmessage-length=0`.

Comment: I thought that too, but I think everything is okay.  My whole line says `-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0-std=c++11`.  I even tried adding a space after the 0, but that resulted in the same except the C++11 commands failed to compile.

Comment: Well, you definitely have to have a space in there to separate the options.

Comment: Alright I've added in the space, but now it it'll just throw a "was not declared" error on all C++11 commands.  Updated the OP.