# Eclipse, minGW and C++11

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, c++11, mingw

I am using Eclipse with the winGW compiler (gcc version 3.4.5). 
I need to use some C++11 features, I have been following several answers to similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support), but it does not work in my case. Eclipse says:

```
cclplus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
cclplus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Does this version of minGW supports C++11?

Comment: To my knowledge, the earliest version of GCC with C++11 is 4.3, and even that is horribly outdated.

Comment: I'm pretty this version **does not** support C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), the earliest GCC version that supports any C++11 features is version `4.3`. The latest MinGW version is `4.8.1`, but your version will indeed not support any C++11 features.