# C++11 Eclipse auto completion is not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-luna, gcc4.8

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).

My auto completion works in general and I can compile correct c++11 files. However features for specific C++11 features don't appear in the auto completion (e.g. emplace_back function for certain containers or new containers such as forward_list).

They compile fine though so that is not the problem.

So far I tried changing the language dialect to c++11 from the project settings. This allows the program to compile fine but no auto completion.

NOTE: The code compiles fine. It's the auto completion that's not working.

Comment: I don't use eclipse, so I can't say if it works, but I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24561615/2417774) could be useful.