# How do I use C++0x on Eclipse Helios?

Tags: c++, eclipse, xcode, g++

I am trying to make use of C++0x on Helios Eclipse.

I followed the instructions from here:

[Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

They won't work.

When I use make -f makefile (in the Debug directory), I get the error:

```
     g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"cnfo.d" -MT"cnf_io.d" -o"cnfo.o" "../cnfo.cpp"
    cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

I am using MacOSx. I re-installed xcode just now, with the latest version.
g++ --version gives:

```
     # g++ --version
     i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
     Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
     This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
     warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I didn't change anything in my project settings other than what it said above in the StackOverflow link.

Comment: Did you also install the command line tools for the latest XCode?

Comment: I am using OSx 10.8 -- I couldn't find command line tools for it, but according to this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html I may not need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t think you´ll get C++11 with G++ 4.2.1, because the implementation started with 4.3 ...
the current versions are 4.9.x, get newer software.

Comment: please see follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222659/why-didnt-my-g-and-gcc-version-get-upgraded