# why didn't my g++ and gcc version get upgraded?

Tags: eclipse, xcode, macos, c++11

I am on a Mac. I updated my OSx to Yosemite. I updated my xcode to version 6. I downloaded the command line tools.

And still, whenever I type in g++ --version, I get:

```
# g++ --version
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.1.0'
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

meaning, I am still using the old version of g++ and gcc.

Why wasn't it upgraded? I am interested in using c++0x in Eclipse, and for that I need a newer g++/gcc compiler.

EDIT: following the comment below, I have two questions:

Why

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

do I still seem to have an old version of clang?

Why didn't the installation of xcode and the command-line tools create the proper links to clang?

Comment: Newest osx/xcode doesn't install a new gcc, it installs a new clang and gives it a gcc alias.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you maybe have an old version of xcode also installed.
From the command line you can switch to the proper one with

```
xcode-select --switch <path>
```

You should see something like this

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing ios-deploy after upgrading to yosemite. i was getting the same

```
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.1.0'
```

for gcc.  I ultimately solved it by:

```
cd /opt/local/bin/
sudo rm gcc
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc gcc
```

This correctly pointed gcc to the the version provided by Xcode 6.1.