# use C++11 features in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I have this piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << std::is_same<int,int>::value;  // this line is underlined (as a error)
    return 0;
}
```

I am not quite used to code C++ in Eclipse.
So I have a Eclipse luna-SR2-32 (latest version), and I use tdm-gcc-4.9.2 as a compiler.

So the issue is that Eclipse underlines that line (look at the code) (`is_same` and `value` couldn't be resolved), however he has no problem including `type_traits`, I can even open it from eclipse Editor, and see that 'is_same' is the file.

When I compile and run it, it works fine but it stills underlined which is bothering me... It doesn't do this with some other c++11 features as `tuple` ...

I know this needs probably a simple configuration in Eclipse, but I tried many things already ... I added `-std=c++11` in the compiler options (but nothing changed).

**EDIT :**

I tried the 3 first answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support), but none of them worked ...
But I tried using  instead and now it is not underlined anymore ... Why is that ? I know that some librairies are in tr1 because they were added later, but why does he recognize  and can run it, but still underlines my lines when I use it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Comment: You should follow the instructions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13549029/969365

Comment: Tried the 3 first answers ... none of them worked