# C++ how to sleep?

Tags: c++, compilation

I am a novice in `C++` and I am struggling to make my program to wait a few minutes before executing a function.

I know there are lots of topics about it but I have a problem with my compiler. I can't seem to use the boost library nor the thread library. And since I can't use the thread library, I can't use the chrono library either.

I am using `GNU GCC` Compiler. I have `MinGW` installed. Is it outdated or something? What is the best compiler to code in `C++`?
My OS is `Windows`.

Comment: sleep(X seconds) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx  (btw, you can use C usleep command to ms sleep)

Comment: What compiler version? `g++ --version` and what flags are you using to compile?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.8.1    Flags are [-s] and [-O2]

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
usleep(1000); // Time in microseconds
```

or

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "windows.h"
    #include "iostream"
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int sleepTime = 1000;
    Sleep(sleepTime);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I tried usleep(300000000); but it was't sleeping at all. stdafx.h is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

`<thread>` is only available starting with C++11.

It's likely you don't have the proper flags to tell GCC you want to enable C++11 support, which is disabled by default.

The command line parameter is `-std=c++11`.

Then, you can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` for cause your program to fall asleep. Note that if you only have one thread in your program, it will probably stop responding to user actions during that time.

Comment: I enabled the C++11 flag and I don't get an error that thread library is not found anymore. However I still do get an error saying 'std::this_thread' has not been declared'.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? It's possible you need to enable the flag in two places - once for Eclipse's parser, and one for the compiler. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9135135/425871) for some details about that, it might help you if this is the case.