# How to enable c++11 in eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, c++11

- I have eclipse Luna.I want to use auto variable in my project and for that i need to enable **c++11** in eclipse.I have followed this answer [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)
- But in my project's property, there are no option like **c/c++ Build.** There are only one option named **c/c++ General**.
- So using **c/c++ general** how can i enable c++11 in my eclipse.Please anybody know the solution then mention steps.thanks.

Comment: Did you check http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features? There's some mention there of a "Dialect" option

Comment: Yes but still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse Luna, go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tools Settings > Cross G++ Compiler (or whichever compiler setting you're using) and choose "ISO C++1y (-std=c++1y)" or "ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x)".  Or instead, in "Other dialect flags", you can put std=c++11, or std=c++14, but if you do it this way you'll probably have to take an additional step not covered here so the Eclipse editor will produce error flagging for the correct C++ version in the editor.