# Method 'shrink_to_fit' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector, stl

I am facing a problem with **shrink_to_fit()** function of STL C++. The problem is which I use it, the compiler gives error "Method 'shrink_to_fit' could not be resolved" on Eclipse Luna (32 bit) with MinGW compiler but the same program works fine in Dev C++.

Image of the program:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Compiler do not recommend shrink_to_fit() after using dot(.):
[image]

Original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   vector<int> v(128);

   cout << "Initial capacity = " << v.capacity() << endl;

   v.resize(25);
   cout << "Capacity after resize = " << v.capacity() << endl;

   v.shrink_to_fit();
   cout << "Capacity after shrink_to_fit = " << v.capacity() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Please let me know is this my fault or IDE's.

P.S. I am using C++14.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` was introduced in C++11. Make sure your ide/compiler flags is set to allow at least C++11

Comment: I am using C++14 i.e. ISO C++1y (-std=c++1y) but still getting error

Comment: I'm just saying I can't reproduce the error you are getting. https://onlinegdb.com/rJMIv9D9r. This seems to be a problem with your IDE

Comment: See if this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/how-to-enable-c11-c0x-support-in-eclipse-cdt or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314814/how-to-enable-c11-in-eclipse-luna

Comment: I know because I ran the same program in Dev C++ and it works fine. But I mainly prefer Eclipse. BTW thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me (with -std=c++11 flag, and MinGW distro from https://nuwen.net/mingw.html#install) on

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers,
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 13.0.1

as well as on Linux (with -std=c++11 flag and GCC 7.4.0 compiler). It could be a problem with your IDE, compiler (with right flag) or STL implementation. There can't be a 4th reason in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.
Try compile 'by hand' to find out if it is about the ide:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo
./foo
```