# Symbol "hash" could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, std

I am using Eclipse as the IDE to develop C++ programs.

I am declaring the following struct:

```
struct std::hash<SomeObject>;
```

However, I got the error message:

> Symbol "hash" could not be resolved

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: And you have `#include <functional>` at the top of your file already?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be using C++11, which introduced the `std::hash` type.  You could add the flag for support (`-std=c++11`) to your compiler options, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135135/1464861) for more info.

Even if the symbol were found, that line would not compile as is.
If you are declaring an instance, you need to give it a name, otherwise it thinks you are forward-declaring a type.  Otherwise, you can use `typedef` or `using` to name the type.

```cpp
#include <functional>

// if you want to declare an instance
struct std::hash<SomeObject> aHashInstance;

// for types, one of:
typedef std::hash<SomeObject> MyHash;
using MyHash = std::hash<SomeObject>;
```