# Why does Eclipse C/C++ indicate errors in cpp files when adding -std=c++11?

Tags: eclipse, c++11

I have a problem with Eclipse C/C++ Code Analysis and CDT.

I have some C++11 code so I had to add support for this to my Eclipse environment. I read several threads about this and found the following answer:

Add the **-std=c++11** flag to *Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Disovery -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler*

After doing this the C++11 functions are now resolved. However alot of new errors has been introduced. These errors only occurs in the ***.cpp** files.
I get errors like *"Member declaration not found"* etc. The interesting this is that if I keep all the class method implementations in the header files I don't get any Eclipse code errors. Also I should add the code compiles if I build the project but Eclipse highlight code errors, so this does only seem to be related to CDT.

NOTE: I have tried several releases of Eclipse, all showing same problem.

I have not been able to find any answer for this problem so please help me.

Comment: Please always show the exact error messages. Also "the code builds fine", where and how if there are errors? Do you mean Eclipse shows errors, but when compiling everything is fine?

Comment: Yes, by building I mean that it builds the project from Eclipse. It compiles and links sucessfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Comment: Have you added the include path to the project's "PATHs and Symbols" for this project? I added /path_to_std_includes/dev/foo/include manually because the location varies from linux dist do dist.