# How do you enable C++11 syntax in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-neon

I am developing C+11 code in Eclipse Neon and noticed today that the range based for loop introduced in C+11 is highlighted red by the IDE indicating it does not recognize it.

I have found multiple links about how to do this for older versions of CDT such as this ([Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)) You can see though there is no "Tool Settings" tab.

[image]

Can someone suggest how to configure my project so that C++11 syntax is correctly highlighted (I am using a separate build system)

Comment: FYI, on some computers (at least mine) Eclipse Neon parser works with C++14 by default. This is probbaly due to the fact that g++ 5.4.0 and later versions compile with C++14 support by default (like you would add command normally, I don't have to), hence Eclipse parser works without need to add -std=c++14 to providers tab.

Conclusion: upgrading compiler can fix parser issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Right click on your project and click Properties
2. Navigate to C/C++ General and Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
3. Select the Providers tab, click on compiler settings row for the compiler you use.
4. Add -std=c++11 to Command to get compiler specs.
5. Apply changes.

Will look something like this:

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}" -std=c++11
```

Comment: FWIW I also had to rebuild the index (right click on your project->Index->Rebuild).

Comment: I also had to do above steps for "All" build configuration.

Comment: this didn't work for me :(
Instead I went to
1. Properties
2. C/C++ Build
3. Settings
4. Dialect
5. put  -std=c++11 in Other dialect flags box
6. Apply and Build

Comment: After executing these steps. Project-> C/C++ index -> Freshen all files

Comment: @Pavel re "having to [change enable c++11] for every project": you can change this setting globally for all eclipse c++ projects. Instead of modifying the configuration for only your project (via: "right click on your project")... instead edit the global configuration for all projects (via: opening the Eclipse menu --> Window --> Preferences --> C/C++ --> Build --> Settings --> Discovery --> "CDT GCC Build-in Compiler Settings" --> then append the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=gnu++0x`).

Comment: It's very important to rebuild the index! I spend half an hour trying to figure out why this solution doesn't work for me. Thank you so much @SyntheticGio

Answer (score 7):

You can also do the following

1. go to project properties (alt enter)
2. In the left pane, scroll to "C/C++ Build", collapse it, select settings.
3. In the right pane, select and collapse your compiler under the Tool
   Settings menu, select"Dialect", choose your languange standard from
   the drop down, or enter -std=c++11 in the "other dialect flags" text
   input.

Alternatively,

1. Properties --> "C/C++ Build" --> collapse and and select "Settings"
2. Under the Tool settings tab, select your compiler, and highlight the
   "Miscellaneous" field.
3. add -std=c++11 to the "Other flags" input field.

Comment: These instructions don't seem accurate for Eclipse Neon CDT.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I do not understand, when searching for clues as to why my Eclispe Oxygen + CDT 9.3.2 running on Fedora 27 could not reliably debug my code, Google put up this question / answer as something to look at.

Basically my problem has been that a fairly simply C++ program, using C++ 11 features (specifically shared_ptr), was un-debuggable in Eclipse Oxygen 2 + CDT 9.3.2 on top of Fedora 27 (which has gdb version 8.0.1 installed from the standard package repo). Stepping into a few method calls resulted in a hung debug session, nothing going on, terminate Eclipse to recover.

If I debugged the binary using gdb on the command line, all was good; I could set break points, etc, everything worked as it should. But from inside Eclipse, nothing doing.

However, putting -std=c++11 into the project settings as shown by Andreas solved the problem. I have very little idea why. I thought I'd put this up in case someone else ran into a similar problem.

g++ is at version 7.2.1

Comment: I guess this solution applies to Eclipse-Oxygen too (in addition to Eclipse-Neon).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason editing the global c++ compiler settings didn't work for me.  Following the instructions to modify the project-specific setting did work.  See: [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing above works for you:
Just check if

```
Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings tab > Dialect
```

Confirm if you have **"ISO C++11 ..."** option in Language standard drop-down Menu.

If yes then select > Apply and close.

I hope this will work.