# Eclipse CDT cannot resolve std:array, std::vector works fine

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, stdarray

I am facing a lot of [image: red crosses] saying `Symbol 'array' could not be resolved`, with code that is building fine.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

static std::string printArray(std::array<double, 3> data) {
  std::ostringstream strs;
  strs << "( " << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " " << data[2] << " )";
  return strs.str();
}

static std::string printVector(std::vector<double> data) {
  std::ostringstream strs;
  strs << "( " ;
  for (const auto & value : data )
      strs << value << " ";
  strs << " )";
  return strs.str();
}
```

The c++11 feature are activated using the `-std=c++11` flag under `C/C++ General -> Preposcessor Include Path, Macros etc. -> Porvides -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134872/how-do-you-enable-c11-syntax-in-eclipse-neon).

My question is no duplicate, since it works for `std::vector` and other c++11 features are handled correctly.

The header (`#include <array>`) can be resolved by pressing F3.

I am using Eclipse the CDT Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

Comment: I dont't get any errors during the build. I am using a Makefile based build.

Comment: @VT, I think it is no dublicate. I did the steps suggested there. They work for `std::vector` but not for `std::array`.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135135/440558) in the question you link to for setting the `-std=c++11` flag, it doesn't mention "Preposcessor[sic] Include Path, Macros etc."

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding Index?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The position of the setting changed from the version Eclipse Indigo 20110615-0604 used in the answer to neo3, which I am using.

Comment: @VTT Yes I have rebuild the index. You have no choice after changing the settings there. I also restarted eclispe, just to be sure.

Comment: The fact that `std::vector`, without any template arguments after it (in the parameter `std::vector data`), **is** resolved, is very suspicious, since `std::vector` is a template type. You said your code compiles, but I don't see how. Can you explain?

Comment: @HighCommander4 sorry something went wrong, when coping the code here. I corrected the code.

Comment: When you open the `<array>` header via F3, do you see a preprocessor condition along the lines of `#if __cplusplus < 201103L`? Where, if that's true, a warning header is included, otherwise you get the actual contents of the header, including the definition of `std::array`? CDT should show you which of those two preprocessor branches it believes to be active, by greying out the inactive one. Which part is greyed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same symptoms that the OP reported:

- I had previously applied the " -std=c++11" fix to make modern C++ things like "unique_ptr" syntax work.
- std::vector and other std template things are resolved without errors.
- I have `#include <array>` and F3 successfully navigates to the array header file.

I tried the solution provided by schorsch312, and it *worked* except the steps presented are not exactly consistent with my Neon version of Eclipse (same version used by OP).  Hence, I had to adjust the instructions slightly.  Here is what worked for me:

1. Select Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> C/C++ Paths and Symbols -> Symbols
2. On that page under Languages, select GNU C++
3. Add...

   - Name: __cplusplus
   - Value: 201103L
4. Check: Add to all configurations
5. Apply / OK.

Select Project -> C/C+ Index -> Rebuild -- if that operation did not automatically trigger.

Now, eclipse can resolve references to array properly.  Note that this solution assumes you have previously resolved the general issue of getting c++11 syntax working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the symbol `__cplusplus` does not have the value 201103L.

To change this you need to

- Edit `Project->Preferences->C/C++ General/C/C+ General->Paths and Symbols->GNU C++->Symbols` add define `__cplusplus` and set value to  `201103L` setzen.
- Add under `Window->Preferences->C/C++/Build/Settings/Discovery/CDT GCC Build-in Compiler Settings` das Argument "-std=c++11" der Command Line hinzufügen
- Activate under `Project->Preferences->C/C++ General/C/C++ General/Path and Symbols->Providers` for all entries the checkbox `Use global provider shared between projects`