# Eclipse Oxygen cannot find any C++ object in standard lib

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc, eclipse-oxygen

I'm having an issue with Eclipse Oxygen where Eclipse cannot find anything in the standard lib:

This is a snippet of code that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <memory>

....

typedef asio::io_service service;
typedef std::shared_ptr<service> servicePtr;
```

The shared_ptr is highlighted with an error saying "Symbol 'shared_ptr' could not be resolved". I receive this error on any object that uses the std:: namespace.

For instance if I have

```
#include <atomic>
....
std::atomic<bool> myBool;
```

Same error as before but Eclipse cannot find Symbol atomic

However the includes do not have any such error saying the header could not be found.

This started happening when I needed to use C++11 using g++ from another directory (/opt/dev/usr/bin/g++) who's --version is g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406

I set that path as the command as my GCC C++ compiler in my Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings.

I also added the /opt/dev/usr/include directory to my Library paths and exported it.

There is also my /usr/include /usr/local/include in the includes which I think may be messing the indexer up but I don't know how to tell Eclipse to ignore those paths.

I'm unsure what I need to do to allow Eclipse to recognize any of the standard libraries again...

Comment: Did you set the language standard? See Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc., Providers tab, CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings entry, look at the "Command to get compiler specs" entry box.  You may need "-std=c++11" in the command line there.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39134872/10077. It's for Neon, but the answer should be the same.