# How to set c++11 for eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've read a number of solutions to this question and they all involve going to C/C++ Build >> Settings and changing something, but in my Eclipse all I have under there is tabs for "binary parsers" and "error parsers", no "Miscellaneous" or "dialectic" or whatever. How do I get around this?

Comment: Found this thread that applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134872/how-do-you-enable-c11-syntax-in-eclipse-neon

Comment: Eclipse Luna is 4 years and 5 releases old, perhaps you need something newer. Eclipse 2018-09 is the current release.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the issue is not related to the Eclipse version, but the project type. The instructions you've been looking at are for choosing C++11 for a **managed build** project.

You probably have a **makefile** project; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134872/how-do-you-enable-c11-syntax-in-eclipse-neon?noredirect=1) for enabling C++11 mode in a makefile project.

(That said, I would still recommend upgrading to a newer version of Eclipse for other reasons, such as much improved C++ parsing support.)