# Installing gcc 6.1 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++, c++14

I installed gcc using mingw. My gcc version is 5.3.0.
My class is teaching in C++ 14.
From my understanding gcc 6.1 or newer defaults in C++ 14 but 5.4 requires me to change some settings. I heard that all I have to do is change a setting on my IDE (Eclipse). I added the  -std=c++14 to that setting, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549029/6612932).

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/17a3a2dee6218b585a64a57a29e83c04.png]

So I did that, but Eclipse still did not understand my test code.

Next I tried downloading gcc using cygwin and following [these instructions](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/).

This gave me gcc version 5.4.0, which is a different version from mingw.
I got to step 3, where it says to add this to the command line:

> $ wget htp://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2.tar.gz  (I removed a t from http so that stackoverflow doesnt change it to a link)
>
> $ tar xf gcc-4.9.2.tar.gz

However, the cygwin terminal did not understand wget.

[image]

Can anyone help me out to get gcc 6.1 or 6.2 on my desktop so I can start coding in C++ 14?

Comment: Have you tried [this specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24561615/3527464)? The enabling and moving in the Providers preferences section has proven useful to me.