# C++14 Syntax in Eclipse CDT compiles but marked as syntax error (indexer)

Tags: eclipse, c++14, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse CDT gives me a syntax error for a valid C++14 syntax.
Everything compiles and runs but the syntax highlighting is broken.

I have MinGW and Eclipse running. The C++14 program compiles and executes but I get incorrect syntax highlighting / syntax checking.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
auto main() -> int
{
    //Binary Literals C++14 with Digit separators C++14
    auto seven = int{0b0000'0111};

    std::cout << seven << std::endl;
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    return int{0};
}
```

And here is the output / build log.
You can see my compiler settings 
(`-D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++14`) and the highlighting in it.

[image]

What do I need to setup so syntax detecition allows for C++14 syntax?

EDIT: it seems like the Indexer is the right bet - I am unable to make the Indexer work as intended.

On Windows 7 I am using MinGW.
I open Providers and click on "CDT Built-In Compiler Settings MinGW" where I add `-std=c++14`. So the whole string is `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}" -std=c++14` after I hit apply and ok I use Project->Index->rebuild in the hope of removing my errors. The Syntax error still persists.

This is essentially what is mentioned in [the FAQ to get C++11 recognized](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features) by the indexer.

I have the latest MinGW Version installed. When I call `g++ --version` i get: `g++ (GCC) 5.3.0` as a response. [There is no manual for 5.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) but I would assume most of 5.4 is mostly valid for my version.

Comment: What message do you see when you hover over the highlighted line?

Comment: Ok I see it myself as just "Syntax error" rather than something more detailed.

Comment: @PeterSW: yeah - it actually just says `Syntax Error`

Comment: Hovering over it and pressing F2 and then pressing the little icon at the bottom left sends me to the annotation preferences which suggest it's coming from the C/C++ Indexer.
Maybe you could adjust the "Built in compiler settings" for the indexer as described in the last post here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1070790/

Comment: @PeterSW did not work for me yet - but I will retry tomorrow. I found a bugreport like that for c++11, I think you are on to something. `https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471621`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the support for C++14 is not added yet.

[Here is a bugreport](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490405) that collects all C++14 issues.
There is a depends on section where other bug reports alre listed. Among them the bug [451086](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451086) that specifically mentions `Binary literals (N3472)`, `Single-quotation-mark as digit separator (N3781)`.

So it seems like this issue is known and will be adressed at some point in the future.