# how can I get maximum , minimum, and position of the vector complex value in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

In Matlab, we can get the max, min, and also the position of the complex vector:

```
[mag_x idx_x] = max(abs(X));
[mag_y idx_y] = max(abs(Y));
```

I know that we can do the similar with C++ because Matlab is build from C++. But I could not figure it out. I also have incomplete code, and still working on it:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::min_element, std::max_element
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

//typedef std::complex < double > C
vector <complex<short> > vec;

vec.push_back ( complex <short> (1,1));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (1,2));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (3,4));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (0,0));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (4,8));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (0,0));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (2,3));
vec.push_back ( complex <short> (1,1));

int size = sizeof(x_vec)/sizeof(x_vec[0]);
for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << x_vec[i] << endl;
}
 ...

return 0;
}
```

I also look at the sample code from this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/ but it work only for vector.

Also when I calculate the `size = sizeof(x_vec)/sizeof(x_vec[0]);` I am expecting size = 8 (because of 8 vector complex above) but I gave me only size = 6.

Comment: when finding the size of the vector, use `vec.size()`. The sizeof calculation is a c-style method, and you're applying it to a vector object (which holds three pointers, usually, and is thus the size of three pointers) and its first element (which will have the size of whatever type the vector stores)

Comment: Additionally, it's unclear exactly what you mean by minimum maximum and position in this context--you could be referring to the entry in the vector with the smallest/biggest magnitude, and getting the index of that element. Or you could be asking for the smaller/bigger of the real and imaginary numbers that make up each complex number, and an indication of which is which.

Comment: In fact, if you want to visit every element in `vec`, use a `range-based for` instead: `for(const auto& c : vec) { cout << c << endl; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `vector<complex>` with `std::max_element`, you need to provide a function which compares the values of two `complex` objects. You need to do this as there's multiple ways to compare them.

One way is to write a lambda function which compares two `complex`es using `std::abs`.  You can write this in your call to `max_element`:

```
// C++14
auto maxelem = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                           [](auto a, auto b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); });
// C++11
auto maxelem = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                           [](const complex<short>& a, const complex<short>& b)
                             { return abs(a) < abs(b); });

cout << "Max: " << *maxelem << endl;
```

`max_element` produces an iterator containing the maximum value found. The index of that iterator in the vector can be found using `std::distance`:

```
cout << "Max position: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), maxelem) << endl;
```

The `complex` comparator function can be stored in an `auto` for reuse:

```
// C++14
auto absLess = [](auto a, auto b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); };
// C++11
auto csAbsLess = [](const complex<short> &a,
                    const complex<short> &b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); };
```

We can use it with various other Standard Library algorithms like `min_element` and `sort`.

```
auto maxelem = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), absLess);
cout << "Max: " << *maxelem << endl;
cout << "Max position: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), maxelem) << endl;

auto minelem = min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), absLess);
cout << "Min: " << *minelem << endl;
cout << "Min position: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), minelem) << endl;

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), absLess);

for (const auto &c : vec) {
  cout << c << endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Max: (4,8)
Max position: 4
Min: (0,0)
Min position: 3
(0,0)
(0,0)
(1,1)
(1,1)
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)
(4,8)
```

Granted, it's not as eloquent as `[mag_x idx_x] = max(abs(X));`!

[An online demonstration is on Wandbox here.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gkKqNKOrPDAuwHJf)

Comment: The [`max_element' documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) shows how to find the position of the max element within the vector - is that what you meant by "Position"?

Comment: Jack Deeth : my answer is "yes". I am trying to convert code from Matlab to C++, it's complicated but it will help me to reduce time process.

Comment: Jack Deeth : I am sorry for the lacking of knowledge, but I would like to ask you a question regarding to the ideal you just suggested. I am using Eclipse platform in Ubuntu OS. when I tried to test with:  auto absLess = [](auto a, auto b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); }; inside  "int main(){...}" but it shows the error: ‘absLess’ does not name a type, with warning  
‘auto’ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]. is that compatible with this platform? Thank you, Jack Deeth.

Comment: That means your compiler isn't running in C++11 / C++14 mode. You need to pass `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` to your compiler. There's instructions on how to do this with Eclipse [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9135135/2449857). (If it's an old compiler, try `-std=c++0x`, which was the working title for what became C++11.)

Comment: still working on it, thank you very much, Jack Deeth .

Comment: My experience with C++: writing the code is fun. Understanding why the compiler won't compile? INFURIATING. And then you figure it out and everything's fine.

Comment: Maybe you should look at fortran, as it has MINLOC, MINVAL etc as intrinsics, and the indexing is MATLAB like. MATLAB shares a lot with Fortran.