# eclipse build error with regex

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc, std

I'm trying to implement regex in my parser program when i used codeblocks all works fine, on eclipse neon im having Function 'regex_match' could not be resolved  error. I added flag to gcc c++ compiler settings -std=c++11 and checked CDT GCC Built-in compiler settings MiniGW.
How to make it work on eclipse ?

```
    #include "ParserSip.h"
    #include <regex> //its included ok

    void checkIfCseq (SipMessage & pointer, string stringLine){     
    string stringToFind = ".*CSeq:.*";  
    regex_match(); // Function 'regex_match' could not be resolved 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support ?

Comment: Yes i did what's included in this post didnt helped my.