# Eclipse Marking std namespace as 'could not be resolved'

Tags: eclipse, c++11, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I am having issues with setting up Eclipse CDT to correctly do development in C++11. It's highlighting `std::error_code` and honestly everything in the std namespace. While the application compiles just fine on the command line.

Screen shot included.

[image]

The full project can be found on `github.com/rbaindourov/OpenWeatherMapDSLink` including the hidden files used by Eclipse.

I can host the the OVA of the virtual machine if you like as well.

Thanks in advance to any industrious individual who is willing to take the time to help me configure Eclipse CDT correctly.

And apologies if my question is not to your liking.

The source for the main.cpp file originally came from:

https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/kinetic-efm-cpp-sdk/blob/master/efm-cpp-sdk-1.0.15-Ubuntu16.04-dslink-dev/examples/simple_responder/main.cpp

```
// @copyright_start
// Copyright (c) 2019 Cisco and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
// @copyright_end

#include <efm_link.h>
#include <efm_link_options.h>
#include <efm_logging.h>

#include "error_code.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>


/// @brief The simple responder link example demonstrates the EFM SDK API for responder implementations. Shows node,
/// action creation, and stream handling.
class SimpleResponderLink
{
public:
  /// Constructs the responder link implementation.
  /// @param link The link to work with.
  SimpleResponderLink(cisco::efm_sdk::Link& link)
    : link_(link)
    , responder_(link.responder())
  {
  }

  /// The initialize callback that will be called as soon as the initialization including serialization is complete.
  /// Will create the first level node hierarchy. Only nodes not created by the deserialization will actually be
  /// created.
  /// @param link_name The name of the link.
  /// @param ec The error code will be set to an error if the initialization failed.
  void initialize(const std::string& link_name, const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (!ec) {
      LOG_EFM_DEBUG(
        "SimpleResponderLink", cisco::efm_sdk::DebugLevel::l1, "Responder link '" << link_name << "' initialized");
    } else {
      LOG_EFM_ERROR(ec, "could not initialize responder link");
    }

    cisco::efm_sdk::NodeBuilder builder{"/"};

    builder.make_node("sdk version")
      .display_name("SDK Version")
      .type(cisco::efm_sdk::ValueType::String)
      .value(link_.get_version_info());
    builder.make_node("text")
      .display_name("String")
      .type(cisco::efm_sdk::ValueType::String)
      .value("Hello, World!")
      .writable(
        cisco::efm_sdk::Writable::Write, std::bind(&::SimpleResponderLink::set_text, this, std::placeholders::_1))
      .on_subscribe(std::bind(&::SimpleResponderLink::on_subscribe_text, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    builder.make_node("set_text")
      .display_name("Set Text")
      .action(cisco::efm_sdk::Action(
                cisco::efm_sdk::PermissionLevel::Read,
                std::bind(
                  &SimpleResponderLink::set_text_called,
                  this,
                  std::placeholders::_1,
                  std::placeholders::_2,
                  std::placeholders::_3,
                  std::placeholders::_4))
                .add_param(cisco::efm_sdk::ActionParameter{"String", cisco::efm_sdk::ValueType::String})
                .add_column({"Success", cisco::efm_sdk::ValueType::Bool})
                .add_column({"Message", cisco::efm_sdk::ValueType::String}));

    responder_.add_node(
      std::move(builder),
      std::bind(&SimpleResponderLink::nodes_created, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  }

  /// Callback that will be called upon construction of the first level nodes.
  /// @param paths The paths of the nodes that were actually created. A path that was added to the NodeBuilder is
  /// not part of the paths vector means that the node was already created. Normally, there is no need to check for
  /// the presence of a path. If the error code signals no error, just continue with your work.
  /// @param ec The error code will be set to an error if the node creation failed.
  void nodes_created(const std::vector<cisco::efm_sdk::NodePath>& paths, const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (!ec) {
      LOG_EFM_DEBUG("SimpleResponderLink", cisco::efm_sdk::DebugLevel::l1, "created nodes");
      for (const auto& path : paths) {
        LOG_EFM_DEBUG("SimpleResponderLink", cisco::efm_sdk::DebugLevel::l2, "created path - " << path);
      }
    }
  }

  /// Called every time the link connects to the broker.
  /// Will set the value on the '/text' path.
  /// @param ec The error code will be set to an error if the connect failed.
  void connected(const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (!ec) {
      disconnected_ = false;
      LOG_EFM_INFO(responder_error_code::connected);

      responder_.set_value(text_path_, cisco::efm_sdk::Variant{"Hello, World!"}, [](const std::error_code&) {});
    }
  }

  /// Called every time the link is disconnected from the broker.
  /// Will set a flag to signal the disconnected status.
  /// @param ec The error code will be set to an error if the disconnect failed.
  void disconnected(const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    LOG_EFM_INFO(responder_error_code::disconnected, ec.message());
    disconnected_ = true;
  }

  /// Will be called the node '/text' is set via an \@set action.
  /// @param value The value that was set.
  void set_text(const cisco::efm_sdk::Variant& value)
  {
    LOG_EFM_INFO(responder_error_code::set_text, value);
  }

  /// Action callback for the '/set_text' action. Will set the value of the path '/text' to the given one. It will also
  /// echo back the set parameter.
  /// The stream will be closed automatically by the link.
  /// @param stream The stream to add a result to.
  /// @param parent_path The path of the node the action was called for.
  /// @param params The parameters set by the peer.
  /// @param ec The error code will be set to an error if the action failed.
  void set_text_called(
    const cisco::efm_sdk::MutableActionResultStreamPtr& stream,
    const cisco::efm_sdk::NodePath& parent_path,
    const cisco::efm_sdk::Variant& params,
    const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    (void)parent_path;
    if (!ec) {
      LOG_EFM_DEBUG("SimpleResponderLink", cisco::efm_sdk::DebugLevel::l3, "set_text_called");
      const auto* input = params.get("String");
      if (input) {
        auto text = *input;
        responder_.set_value(text_path_, text, [stream, text](const std::error_code& ec) {
          if (!ec) {
            stream->set_result(cisco::efm_sdk::UniqueActionResultPtr{new cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult{
              cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult(cisco::efm_sdk::ActionSuccess).add_value(true).add_value(text)}});
          } else {
            stream->set_result(cisco::efm_sdk::UniqueActionResultPtr{
              new cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult{cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult(cisco::efm_sdk::ActionError)
                                                       .add_value(false)
                                                       .add_value("Could not set value")}});
          }
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    stream->set_result(cisco::efm_sdk::UniqueActionResultPtr{
      new cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult{cisco::efm_sdk::ActionValuesResult(cisco::efm_sdk::ActionError)
                                               .add_value(false)
                                               .add_value("Could not set value")}});
  }

  /// Will be called if a subscribe or unsubscribe is issued for the '/text' node.
  /// @param subscribe True if a subscribe was done or false if an unsubscribe was done.
  void on_subscribe_text(bool subscribe)
  {
    if (subscribe) {
      LOG_EFM_INFO(responder_error_code::subscribed_text);
    } else {
      LOG_EFM_INFO(responder_error_code::unsubscribed_text);
    }
  }

private:
  cisco::efm_sdk::Link& link_;
  cisco::efm_sdk::Responder& responder_;
  cisco::efm_sdk::NodePath text_path_{"/text"};

  bool disconnected_{true};
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cisco::efm_sdk::FileConfigLoader loader;
  cisco::efm_sdk::LinkOptions options("Simple-Responder-Link", loader);
  if (!options.parse(argc, argv, std::cerr)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  cisco::efm_sdk::Link link(std::move(options), cisco::efm_sdk::LinkType::Responder);
  LOG_EFM_INFO(::responder_error_code::build_with_version, link.get_version_info());

  SimpleResponderLink responder_link(link);

  link.set_on_initialized_handler(
    std::bind(&SimpleResponderLink::initialize, &responder_link, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  link.set_on_connected_handler(std::bind(&SimpleResponderLink::connected, &responder_link, std::placeholders::_1));
  link.set_on_disconnected_handler(
    std::bind(&SimpleResponderLink::disconnected, &responder_link, std::placeholders::_1));

  link.run();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: First things first: have you configured your project to be in C++11 mode, as described in e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001437)?

Comment: Found it. Window Menu->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Settings https://imgur.com/a/ofY9ulo

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: At first I thought it did, but it still showed in the problems window, and a little while later the highlights showed up again. So, no I'm sorry, I still have the same issue. Adding -std=C++11 to that screen didn't help. I do have multiple compiler's selected though. its not just one, the CDT GCC Built-in Compiler.