# Anyone know how I should set up my Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, gcc, download, g++, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded the Eclipse IDE, as well as mingw, and have mingw in my path. This is the code Eclipse shows when it first is downloaded:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Hello_World.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Right now Eclipse says cout and endl can not be resolved, which is because my include has the following error: Unresolved inclusion:

On further inspection, g++ and gcc isn't downloaded which can be the cause of all these errors. I'm new to cpp, (used python before) and I have no idea what g++ or gcc means, and don't know how to download them. Anyone have any suggestions on where I could download g++ and gcc and what to do next?

Also, can you save an eclipse file and submit it to USACO and still have USACO work even though my computer doesn't have g++ and gcc?

Thanks in advance!
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Which OS? If Windows, download MinGW. If Linux, use `sudo apt-get install gcc g++` or something like that.

Comment: I am on Windows @kiner_shah, and have already downloaded MinGW as the question states.

Comment: Have you configured Eclipse so that it correctly takes the MinGW as the C++ compiler? You may need to set the paths to g++, gcc, etc.

Comment: I think so, but do you have any suggestions on how I should check if I have done so?

Comment: It's been some time I used Eclipse, but usually should be in properties or preferences somewhere. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135135/4688321).