# Eclipse polymorphism using C++11 shared_ptr error

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

Given the following sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {
public:
    A(int aa) : a(aa) {}
    int a;
    virtual ~A() {}
};
struct B : A {
public:
    B(int aa, int bb) : A(aa), b(bb) {}
    int b;
};

void f(shared_ptr<A> a){
    shared_ptr<B> b = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a);
    if (b) {
        cout << b->b << endl;
    } else {
        cout << a->a << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_shared<A>(3);
    auto b = make_shared<B>(7, 4);
    f(a);
    f(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Eclipse indicates that there is an error on the line

```
f(b);
```

saying `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void f(std::shared_ptr<A>) '`
because a `shared_ptr<B>` has been passed. This compiles and runs, and has output:

```
3
4
```

as expected.

The indexer and compiler have -std=c++11 specified.
The compiler also has the symbol `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` defined.

Is there any way to get rid of this error and its red squiggles in Eclipse (preferably without modifying the source)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in later versions of CDT (I just tried it).

You can use a nightly build of CDT using this repository: 
Go to Help, and enter the url http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/kepler/nightly

If you don't feel like using a nighty build, you should at least make sure you have the latest released version (at this writing it is 8.1.1), using http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno/

My full setup of eclipse with C++11 is found here:
http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36441490955/eclipse-mingw-builds

Comment: Oh wow, that's good to hear. I'll give that a shot as soon as I get home today.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you disable the Static Code Analysis plugin Codan in the settings it probably does not support C++11 yet.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that does solve the problem, but I actually like having the red squiggles there when I've actually given a function invalid arguments.

Comment: The problem with Codan is that it gives way too many false positives. You can of course check if there is a specific checker which gives you problems and disable just that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do for now in lieu of a better solution. Thanks for the suggestion.